# POI read file without updating file timestamp

Tags: java, apache-poi

It appears that one can open an Excel file using

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myFile);
```

...but then, even if no changes are made, a call to

```
wb.close();
```

...to release resources will result in the file on the file system being updated (at least the timestamp will be, if nothing else). The only way I have found around this is to specify that the Workbook should be created "read only" with

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myFile, true);
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

- I want to open an existing Workbook from a File;
- Immediately release any filesystem resources, but retain the Workbook in memory; (this should not update the timestamp of the original file);
- Make changes to the in-memory Workbook;
- Save the modified Workbook to a new file.

Is this possible? I've tried many things, but can't seem to get it to work. If I don't want the original file timestamp updated, it seems I have to open the Workbook as read only. But then I can't modify it in memory for a subsequent write to a new file. Catch-22.

[BTW, I'm creating the Workbook from a File rather than a stream, as I understand it is more efficient. If I used a stream I could possibly get around this issue by closing the stream myself. Also, I'm working with XLSX/XLSM not XLS files.]

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Did you [read the Apache POI FAQ on the various read and write methods](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1023C)? Can you work with `.xls` rather than `.xlsx`? (The former currently, as of 3.15 beta 2 / 3.15 final, has better developed support for in-place write and writing to new files)

Comment: Thanks for the info and the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm mostly locked into using XLSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options could be:

1. Create a copy of the file and read/write on the copy
2. Open the original file as read-only, then create a copy to write if required
3. Use an input stream from the original file to create the workbook

Comment: Good thought. The thing is, I will only know after reading the file whether a subsequent write will be necessary. (That's a user decision.) As such, I want to read the file, release resources, and then only create a new file later if necessary. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see, if you don't want to create and delete a file (if no modification required), then you might need to open the file in read only mode, and if a modification is required, create a copy and re-open the copy for modification.

Comment: Oh, OK, I was hoping to avoid that (due to the cost of opening the file, which could be fairly large). Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it will mean reading the file twice, so copying the file first and deleting it if no modification is required might be more efficient. I'd also suggest trying to create the workbook with a stream, although as you said, POI can be inefficient when working with streams, but might be worth a try. So you have three options to try: 1) Create a copy of the file and delete if not modification required. 2) Read the file twice (once in read only-mode) 3) Use a stream to create the workbook.

Comment: Thanks. Something else which might work is to open the OPCPackage myself, read in the workbook (by passing the package to the XSSFWorkbook constructor), and then calling revert() on the package, which should release the resources without writing anything back to the file. Still need to test it, but I'm hopeful.

Comment: Doesn't seem it's going to work, unfortunately. Working with the OPCPackage directly allows me to open the Workbook as read/write, release the resources, and then edit the Workbook in memory. But when I try to write it out to a new file, it complains that the Zip file is closed. I guess, using the File read method, it doesn't read in everything it would need to write out the file again (whereas with the Stream read method it does). At least that's the theory. Seems your options are fairly complete. Thanks for the help! I accepted your answer (but couldn't up vote).

Comment: This answer helped me fixing similar issue, I will add an answer separately to highlight that here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was trying to read an existing excel file for template purpose using

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:legend_wb.xlsx"));
```

Updating data in memory and sending it as OutputStream for download through REST API but failed to notice that in subsequent downloads whenever sheet had less data, old rows were also coming so basically it as overwriting the cells for whatever data sheet had.

Coming to this question, and following point 3, I wrote following.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:legend_wb.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

Above code helps to create a copy of existing excel in memory without needing to work on existing excel file directly and also keeps your original excel file intact without any modifications.